# How can I make this header like in the image? And how can I reuse it easily on multiple pages?

Tags: header-footer, report, tasks

Does anybody know how I can make this header in LaTex? I want it like it is in the image.

Is it somehow possible to reuse it easily? I wanted to use it for multiple homework assignments and tasks for the university?

[image]

[image: This is an example of how the task now is in Microsoft Word.]

[![This is the picture of the header][3]][3]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you call a header? The kind of logo  with a dark red background, or the whole image?

Comment: I didn't know what the exact term is. But I would like to put all my tasks in 1 project and every task should begin with this heading at the top. The image should align with the text with the image at the left and the text at the right.

Comment: Where can we get the image on the left?

Comment: I have uploaded the image here. It's the last picture.

Comment: There's no link, but never mind: I've found Leuven Catholic High School.

Comment: Remark: check if your institution provides a vector image of the logo on its website.

Comment: I did not yet use it, but I think the package `fancyhdr` could be an option: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pain is to align the tops; just use `\raisebox`, for this. I had to adjust it because the image you provide has a white border at the top.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\mbox{\large\sffamily\bfseries
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+2.5pt}{%
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{KHLeuven}%
  }\quad
  \raisebox{-\height}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    2TI Reeks X \ Date: \\
    Communicatie in het Frans: Deel 2 \\
    Pr\'esentation de son site web \\
    Nom:
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For multiple usage, just add the code in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\mylogo}{%
  \mbox{\large\sffamily\bfseries
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+2.5pt}{%
      \includegraphics[width=4cm]{KHLeuven}%
    }\quad
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      2TI Reeks X \ Date: \\
      Communicatie in het Frans: Deel 2 \\
      Pr\'esentation de son site web \\
      Nom:
      \end{tabular}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\mylogo

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to do that: one uses the plain tex macros package `insbox` and its `InsertBoxL{no of lines not indented}{box inserted}[optional no of extralines indented for correction]

The second solution uses the `lettrine` package, with an image replacing the letterused as a lettrine.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, graphicx, eqparbox, lettrine, }
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}
%
\InsertBoxL{0}{\eqmakebox[G]{\includegraphics[scale=0.333]{khleuven_logo.png}}}
{\linespread{1.25}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\eqboxwidth{G}\relax}{\sffamily\bfseries%
2 TI Reeks X\quad Date: \\
 Communicatie in het Frans: Deel 2\\
 Présentation de son site web\\
 Nom: }}
\vskip1cm

\lettrine[image = true, lines=3, lraise=-0.1]{khleuven_logo.png}{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\sffamily\bfseries}l@{}}
    2 TI Reeks X\quad Date: \\
     Communicatie in het Frans: Deel 2\\
     Présentation de son site web\\
     Nom:
 \end{tabular} }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oke, looking good thank you very much. This is a great start.

Comment: It would be nice if you have an `.eps` or `.pdf` version of the logo, so it's really scalable.

Comment: yeah, but this is the previous logo. Now we have a new logo that I have and is scalable very good. but we have to use the previous logo for tasks that we're made with that logo. Stupid rule but I have to keep me too it.